# How to copy a read-only directory in Perl?

Tags: perl, copy

I'm using `File::Copy::Recursive::dircopy( $original_dirname, $new_dirname ) or die $!;` to copy a read-only directory from within a Perl script. I get a `Permission denied` error.

I can see that `$new_dirname` is created, but is marked as read only (like the original directory). Maybe this prevents from the content to be copied into it?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this definitely seems to be a bug in `File::Copy::Recursive`.  A temporary work around is to set `$File::Copy::Recursive::KeepMode` to 0 and do the `chmod` yourself.

It appears to have already been [reported](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=41778) and the author is working on a fix, but it was coming "soon" on 2009-05-20 and "this weekend" on 2010-04-14.